# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:-1).state:5 when using Paging 3

Tags: android

I am using Paging 3 to load a paged list from the network and setting it to an adapter using submitData()

When looking at the crashlytics i can see that there is a crash reported with following dump:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:-1).state:5 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{cf3dbb6 VFED..... ......ID 24,48-1056,1896 #7f0a0538 app:id/rv_sku_order_item_list}, adapter:com.awantunai.app.home.cart.ordering.add_to_cart.SkuAdapter@9a1caa, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager@bd6309b, context:com.awantunai.app.home.cart.ordering.add_to_cart.AddToCartV2Activity@23d548a
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6364)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:98)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1581)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.scrollBy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:2154)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fixEndGap(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1392)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:706)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:604)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4255)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4010)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
       at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1841)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1841)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:877)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23147)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6475)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3272)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2266)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8854)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1473)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1270)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:981)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1458)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:263)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8296)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
```

Following is the code I am using to set data to adapter:

```
viewModel.skuList.collectLatest {
                adapter.submitData(it)
}
```

Following is the code in viewmodel which uses a channel to send search query and request paginated list:

```
val skuList = _searchChannel.receiveAsFlow().flatMapLatest {
        skuRepository.fetchSku(it.activeOrderId, it.supplierId,
            it.name, it.fetchDiscounted, it.skuCategoryIdCombinedText).cachedIn(viewModelScope).map { pagingData ->
            adjustListForSkuDiscount(pagingData)
        }
    }
```